# Unusual Behaviour while passing an array to a function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5

void func(int*);
int main(void)
{
  int i, arr[SIZE];
  for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
          printf("Enter the element arr[%d]: ", i);
          scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        }//End of for loop

  func(arr);
  printf("The modified array is : ");

  for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);

  return 0;

}

  void func(int a[])
 {
   int i;

   for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    a[i] = a[i]*a[i];
 }
```

Output :::

[image]

While I'm entering integer elements the output is OK.But as I entered a float value like 1.5, it didn't ask for other elements and the O/P is as shown in the figure.I think it should implicitly typecast 1.5 to 1 but it didn't happen..can u plz tell why this happened ? All the info about the compiler is shown in the figure.

Comment: Let this be a lesson not to use `scanf`.

Comment: @R.. I think u've some problem with all my questions I've asked till now ...I didn't find any problem in the for loop or with the scanf.If u know something more then u can tell me.

Comment: @R.. U may b genius but i'm not..I want 2 learn from mistakes but wt the mistake here ..??

Comment: @Parixit, I think what R is trying to say (and I'm definitely going to say it) is that `scanf` is not really suited for user input. User input is a very 'fluid' thing, and `scanf` is better suited for formatted data. It's okay for little test programs and homework type stuff but I wouldn't be using it in robust code.

Comment: @paxdiablo  thnx ..I got it..

Comment: @paxdiablo: thanks for clarifying my comment which was less clear than I'd hoped it would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `scanf("%d")` a value like `1.5` the scanning will stop at the decimal point and return 1.

The *next* time you call `scanf`, the pointer will *still* point to the decimal point and your scan will return immediately because there are no digits there to scan.

You should be checking the return value from `scanf` - it gives you the number of items successfully scanned which will be 1 initially for the `1` before the decimal point, and 0 from then on.

As an aside, `scanf` stands for "scan formatted" and I'll guarantee you won't find anything *more* unformatted than user input.

Investigate looking into `fgets` for line input. Here's a copy of a function I often use for such purposes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OK       0
#define NO_INPUT 1
#define TOO_LONG 2
static int getLine (char *prmpt, char *buff, size_t sz) {
    int ch, extra;

    // Get line with buffer overrun protection.
    if (prmpt != NULL) {
        printf ("%s", prmpt);
        fflush (stdout);
    }
    if (fgets (buff, sz, stdin) == NULL)
        return NO_INPUT;

    // If it was too long, there'll be no newline. In that case, we flush
    // to end of line so that excess doesn't affect the next call.
    if (buff[strlen(buff)-1] != '\n') {
        extra = 0;
        while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF))
            extra = 1;
        return (extra == 1) ? TOO_LONG : OK;
    }

    // Otherwise remove newline and give string back to caller.
    buff[strlen(buff)-1] = '\0';
    return OK;
}
```

```
// Test program for getLine().

int main (void) {
    int rc;
    char buff[10];

    rc = getLine ("Enter string> ", buff, sizeof(buff));
    if (rc == NO_INPUT) {
        // Extra NL since my system doesn't output that on EOF.
        printf ("\nNo input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (rc == TOO_LONG) {
        printf ("Input too long [%s]\n", buff);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("OK [%s]\n", buff);

    return 0;
}
```

Once you get a line in with that function, you can `sscanf` it to your heart's content, handling errors much easier.

Comment: +1 As I read on c.l.c: "[E]veryone at some point writes some kind of `fgets()` wrapper (and a study of the different design choices might be interesting to behavioral psychologists)."

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is that `scanf` stops reading an integer when it sees the `'.'` character, and leaves it in the input buffer. Then subsequent calls to `scanf` fail because the next character is `'.'` and not something parseable as an integer.

How do you fix this? The first step is to forget you ever heard of `scanf` and always use `fgets` to read whole lines of input, then process them after you read them into a string buffer. You can use `sscanf` for this purpose, but a robust function like `strtol` would be a lot better.

Answer (score -2):

Problem with buffer - I think the remaining part (.5) remains on the buffer.
use `flushall();` after your `scanf("%d..`

Comment: C has no such function `flushall`.

Comment: @R - Thanks for bringing that to my notice - I code on Windows with VS - so I thought it would work.